# Why are const return types in C possible?

Tags: c

Are there any practical use-cases when it is beneficial to define a **return value as const** in C? If no, why is it even possible to implement it like that?

For example the following code compiles without any problem:

```
int main(){
    int myValue = myFunction();
    myValue++;

    return 0;
}

const int myFunction(){
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do with the return value of a function that would conflict with `const`ness, so explicitly declaring return values `const` is not significant.  Why then is it possible to declare return types `const`?  Presumably because it is easier, more consistent, and friendlier to accept it, and would serve no useful purpose to reject it.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso, `const int* function()` does not declare that `function()` returns a `const` value.  It returns a non-`const` pointer to a `const int`.  I agree that that could be useful, but it's not an example of the situation described in the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, "Any attempt to modify an object with temporary lifetime results in undefined behavior" (C17 6.2.4/8).  I'll grant that there is a difference between "you can't express it" and "it produces UB", but I'm satisfied with my original statement's wording for most purposes.

Comment: It's just to keep the constness system coherent and obey same rules everywhere.